# Error de contexto en ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android-studio, android-context

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial sobre ViewPager2 todo funciona perfecto, el problema es que deseo cargar imagenes con Glide, pero no logro hacerlo por un problema al parecer de contexto.

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(
    private val imagesList: List<Int>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.ViewPagerHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_pager, parent, false)
        return ViewPagerHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.ivSliderImage.setImageResource(imagesList[position])
        Glide.with(this)   //aqui muestra el error
            .load(imagesList[position])
            .into(holder.itemView.otro)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return imagesList.size
    }


    class ViewPagerHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    }
}
```

En mi Fragmento tengo esto

```
val imagesList = listOf(
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.one)

        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(imagesList)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: Es que `this` hace referencia a la clase, que en este caso es un Adapter... un adapter no es un `Context` válido normalmente (a no ser que haya cambiado esto, hace bastante que no toco android), los `context` son `activity` y `fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

`Glide.with()` requiere un Context, un Fragment o una View. Al escribir `this` te estás refiriendo a la clase, que en este caso es un Adapter. Por lo tanto el error es que no coinciden los tipos. Para corregirlo simplemente escribe `Glide.with(holder.itemView)`